# Cannot able to establish an UDP connection between a client and server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, datagram

Basically, I am writing a simple TCP-UDP multiclient GUI program. I can establish a `TCP` connection to the server but not an `UDP` connection. The server is listening in on port `4000.` I have a `comboBox` on the GUI client which has elements `TCP` and `UDP.` If the user selects `UDP` and clicks `Connect.` Then it will attempt to establish a `UDP` connection by calling the `UDPconnection` method.

**Here is my code for the client GUI:**

```
public void UDPconnection()
{
    try
    {
        done = false;
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        done = true;
        System.out.println("Host not available");
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for the chat server:**

```
public class chatServer2 implements Runnable {

    private int clientCount = 0;
    private ChatServerThread clients[] = new ChatServerThread[50];
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    Thread thread = null;

    //same as version3
    public chatServer2(int port){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);//step1
            System.out.println("Started the server...waiting for a client");
            start(); //the chatserver's start method that goes ahead and creates a new thread
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("ERROR "+e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    public void start(){
        if(thread == null){
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {//same as version 3
        while(thread !=null){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");
                //now we add a new Thread and accept a client
                addThread(server.accept());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addThread(Socket socket){
        if(clientCount < clients.length){
            clients[clientCount] = new ChatServerThread(this, socket);
            try {
                clients[clientCount].open();//open the stream for the ChatServerThread client
                clients[clientCount].start();//start to run the ChatServerThread client
                clientCount++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public synchronized void handle(int ID, String input)
    {
        System.out.println(input);

        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
        {
            remove(ID);//person said bye so remove them
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(input);
            for (int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++)
            {

                clients[i].send("User: " + ID + ": " + input);
            }
        }

    }



    public synchronized void remove(int ID){
        int position = findClient(ID);
        if(position >=0){
            ChatServerThread toRemove = clients[position];
            if(position <clientCount-1){
                for(int i= position+1; i <clientCount; i++){
                    clients[i-1] = clients[i];
                }
                clientCount--;
            }
            try {
                toRemove.close();//close the person's that said bye connection
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    private int findClient(int ID){
        for(int i=0; i<clientCount; i++){
            if(clients[i].getID() == ID){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;//not in the array
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        chatServer2 l = new chatServer2(4000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as a 'UDP connection', for a start.
2. Failure to create a `DatagramSocket` on a specified port does *not* mean 'host not available'. Have a look at the exception message to see what it does mean.
3. UDP does not interoperate with TCP, and specifically not with Java `ServerSockets`. You need a `DatagramSocket` or `DatagramChannel` at both ends, and there is no connect phase: you just send datagrams back and forth.